Books to read as an intro to existential philosophy
I'm new to this SE, so correct me if this isn't an appropriate question form for this site.
I've read Plato's The Republic and a few novels by Dostoyevsky (though I know he isn't technically a philosopher more than a novelist, though he has existential themes in his writing. I want to get into some more existential philosophy, but because there's so much to read, I'm not sure where to start.
Although there are a few similar questions of this sort on this site, I'm specifically interested in existential philosophy, not just the general subject.
Should I just dive into another book randomly, read some more modern philosophers, or try something specific? Any suggestions/opinions would be appreciated, thanks.

This question is similar to: What are some good introductions to philosophy?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Welcome AnnOfYellowGables!
Technically a philosopher is itself quite a philosophically contentious question, so writers like Dostoevsky and Camus, despite their lack of academic credentials are generally taken to be philosophers of a sort. If you are looking to understand existentialism (and who wouldn't after having an existential crisis of their own), then you might want to start in three places (from easiest and least reliable to most).

WP - Existentialism
IEP - Existentialism
SEP - Existentialism

There are of course a wide range of existential thinkers, but one of the most influential is Sartre, who is also a "technical philosopher" too! Consider looking over related articles about him.

WP - Jean-Paul Sartre
IEP - Sartre's Political Philosophy
SEP - Jean-Paul Sartre

Existentialism of course is a fascinating philosophy with it's humanistic emphasis. One last source of existentialism can be found in the works of Albert Camus, who absolutely rejected the label as an existentialist, but is often considered in conjunction with them, particularly with his close relationship with Sartre, being fellow French intellectuals.

WP - Absurdism
WP - Albert Camus
IEP - Albert Camus
SEP - Albert Camus


Thank you for the recommendations! I'll look into those!
